# Inserting to table where table name is a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert into a table where the table name is a variable. I can insert to the table just fine but when I try and make it a variable I get problems. I probably just don't know the syntax very well.

Below is without the variable

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test (item) VALUES (?)');
```

Below is what I need

```
$type     = 'test';
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO' + $type + '(item) VALUES (?)');
```

I also tried doing an escape_string

```
$type     = 'send';
$type     = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
```

I'm pretty sure my syntax is just off.

Comment: Um.. that should be `' . $type . '` ? And you probably don't even need the dots, nor the plus sign. This is not JS. [`vinodadhikary's`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20754515/1415724) answer is by far the only one that got it right so far.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for directing me to the correct answer.

Comment: This would have also worked `INSERT INTO $type (item)` but it's always better to wrap `it` with backticks. `$it="your_table";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$type     = 'test';
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$type}` (item) VALUES (?)");
```

Also note that PHP uses dot `.` not plus `+` as string concatenation operator.  But using double quoted string for the query you can use the table variable within the string and the variable gets interpolated.

Comment: I'm wondering why the others are so dead set on keeping the plus signs, baffles the heck out of me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Glad you know what you are doing.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to give a reason for the downvote?  Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing spaces on either side.

`'INSERT INTO ' . $type . ' (item) VALUES (?)'`

would work because the `$type` would be separated by spaces on either side.

Note the space after `INTO` and the space before `(item)`.

Comment: what does mean plus sign?

Comment: I'm wondering that too, and also who upvoted this. `+` is for JS, if anything. @EmilioGort